# Selenium + Cloudflare - trouble to access page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cloudflare, seleniumbase

I'm stucked to access this website - https://...

The cloudflare is blocking the selenium driver.

Currently i'm using https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase that suports undetected driver, but not works.

I've tried selenium stealth and undetected driver, but not works.

Can you help me?

Currently, i'm stucked in this page.

[image]

Whenever I click on input to check if I am human, the page auto reload and waits the click again, generating a loop in this page.

If it can be resolved using playwright or something else, it's fine for me!

edit: removed url, but's solved with comment!

Comment: I am suffering the same in other sites. I guess Cloudflare has flagged some specific attributes from Chromedriver, so we need to wait for a new version to come out.

Comment: @Jausk this lib solved my problem - https://github.com/g1879/DrissionPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lib has solved my problem - https://github.com/g1879/DrissionPage